# Problem regarding loops. I need to access 10 labels through a loop in java?

Tags: java, loops

I have a problem regarding loops. I need to access 10 labels which have names like label1, label2, label3 .... etc. I need to know whether I can access those labels by going through a loop in java?

Comment: this sounds horrible. You should restructure that code

Comment: More detail? What are labels? Why not put them into an array?

Comment: Do you mean these? http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Label.html

Comment: Please clarify your question, the answers are using JLabel objects, but your question sounds like if you where asking about "goto labels" inside a for loop!

Answer (score 5):

How about using `List` or an `array`

```
List<JLabel> labels = new ArrayList<JLabel>();
labels.get(index);
```

Answer (score 4):

Change those labels to be an array, and access it using an index.

For example:

```
JLabel[] labels = new JLabel[10];
for (int i = 0; i < labels.length; ++i) {
    labels[i] = new JLabel("Label " + i);
}
for (int i = 0; i < labels.length; ++i) {
    // access each label.
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Put your labels in to LinkList or array
Then you can access those array or linkList on a loop

Answer (score 2):

If you cannot change the labels names / put them into an array you can make an array of references to the labels and fill it at the beginning of your program with the list of your labels.

Answer (score 0):

'Access to labels' is kinda vague. Are you referring to different instances of java.awt.label? If so you can simply loop over them when they're in a list with a for-each statement.

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about Java labels, you can use a switch statement instead.  If you are talking about objects such as a JLabel, use an array or ArrayList.